# How to use next value for MySQL trigger ?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, db2

I have created a sample table in MySQL with following query .

```
create table table_1 (
  arg1 bigint not null unique,
  arg2 bigint not null default 0,
  arg3 bigint not null default 0,
  agr4 bigint not null default 0,
  arg5 bigint not null default 0,
  constraint shdk_test foreign key(arg1) references arg1(id) 
  on delete cascade on update restrict
);
```

Now i am trying to run a trigger with following command

```
   insert into table_1(arg1, arg2, arg3, agr4, arg5) values(new.id, 
   (next value for revision), (next value for revision), (next value for revision), (next value for revision));
```

After running this trigger , i am getting error on `next value for revision` . I want to know whether `next value for` is supporting in MySQL ? It is supporting in DB2 or any alternative for MySQL ? please help .

Comment: MySQL does not support sequences I believe, so obviously none of the sequence-related statements from other SQL dialects will work.

Answer (score -1):

NEXT VALUE FOR and NEXTVAL are SQL variation commands for Transact-SQL and Oracle respectively. Other SQL databases, including MySQL, do not support that.

Digging over on Stack Exchange DBA I came across this post:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/mysql-get-next-unique-value-without-auto-increment/19020#19020

Or you could after the create table use an insert similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 SELECT arg2 = (SELECT MAX(arg2) + 1 FROM table_1);
```

and do the same with the other arg columns. A procedure could make this more automatic and you could call it when inserting rows.

Comment: I have already defined in DB2 like   `CREATE SEQUENCE revision BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 4611686018427387903 CYCLE CACHE 1000;`  . and i am using that revision as `next value for revision` . How can i do this also ? any suggestions ?

Comment: This answer is wrong.. There can be only just ONE auto_increment column per table.

Comment: This also ignores the fact that, even if multiple columns are allowed, the values would all increment at the same time, and thus are derivable at insert time (ie - use a trigger/computed column, not another autoincrement).

Comment: Edited answer to address comments Raymond & Clockwork-Muse